# Implement a generic stack container as an adaptor class template

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, stack

I'm having some trouble in my Data Structures (cop 4530) class. I need to "Implement a generic Stack container as an adaptor class template". My template and the implementation are in two different files stack.h and stack.hpp **(this is required)**. **I wanted to do this Stack set up as an Array**, but it seems as though my teacher set it us up to do it as a linked list if I'm not wrong?? **I'm just confused on how to get started setting up the stack as an Array** if someone could explain it to me (we have a very useless book). And all I really need is someone to explain to me just a **few** of the functions from ".hpp" where I implement my Stack code. Particularly the copy / move functions. (If it's better or easier for me to do it a different way than I'm trying then please share)

Here's Stack.h; These are all interfaces of the "Stack class Template" we needed to include

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX_SIZE 100

namespace cop4530{

template<typename T>
class Stack{

 private:
 int A[MAX_SIZE];
 int top;

 public:

 Stack();
 ~Stack();
 Stack (const Stack<T>&);
 Stack(Stack<T> &&);
 Stack<T>& operator= (const Stack <T>&);
 Stack<T> & operator=(Stack<T> &&);
 bool empty() const;
 void clear();
 void push(const T& x);
 void push(T && x);
 void pop();
 T& top();
 const T& top() const;
 int size() const;
 void print(std::ostream& os, char ofc = ' ') const;  

}

 //non-member global functions
 std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Stack<T>& a);
 bool operator== (const Stack<T>&, const Stack <T>&);
 bool operator!= (const Stack<T>&, const Stack <T>&);
 bool operator< (const Stack<T>& a, const Stack <T>& b); 

 #include "Stack.hpp"

}

#endif
```

And here's the separate "Stack.hpp" file that holds the implementation of some of them.

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace cop4530{

template<typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack(){
//zero argument constructor
}

template<typename T>
Stack<T>::~Stack(){ //destructor
    clear();
}

template<typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const Stack<T>&){ //copy constructor

}

template<typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack(Stack<T> &&){ //move constructor

}

template<typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack<T> & Stack<T>::operator=(const Stack<T> &){
    //copy assignment operator=
}

template<typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack<T> & Stack<T>::operator=(Stack<T> &&){
    //move assignment operator=
}

/*does this look right? I don't think so...*/
template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& x){ //adds x to the stack, copy version
    insert(begin(), x);
}

template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(T && x){ // adds x to the stack, move version
    insert(begin(), std::move(val));
}
```

Comment: I know!!!! I'm forced to do it this way. I would love to make them in the same file but I can't. This is what's causing some of my confusion

Comment: You should move `#include "Stack.hpp"` outside of the `namespace`.

Comment: @awesomeyi You may have the template in as many files as you like, as long as they are all header files. Note the second file has an `hpp` extension.

Comment: @n.m. Good eyes, I didn't see that

Comment: @awesomeyi: it is perfectly fine to split declaration and implementation in separated (header) files, (I don't like the chosen extensions, I would prefer `.h` and `.inl`).

Comment: include guards seems missing.

Comment: You don't have an adaptor class template. An adaptor class template would look like this: `template <typename T, typename Container=std::vector<T>> class Stack { ... }`. This `Stack` adapts a container of any suitable type, the default is `std::vector` but you can use `std::list` or `std::deque` or something of your own design.

Comment: @n.m. thanks that helps. I do prefer to use vector over list or deque. But i'm still a little bit confused though on how this'll work with the code. If I create a new container in the Stack class will it automatically be of a std::vector type? And as for stack.hpp, how would I go about doing one of those copy / move constructors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement the Stack as a adapter class for array you should really start from the basic functionality of a stack. Let's consider a few basics:

- constructor- created an empty stack
- isFull/isEmpty - return true/false depending on how much space is available in your stack.
- push - adds one element at the top of the queue
- pop - removes the first element from the top of the queue

Let's start with the **constructor**: you could say that your stack is empty when **top == -1**. Since your array is statically allocated (you can consider to dynamically allocate memory for the array in the constructor), all you need to do is `top =-1` and you have yourself an **empty stack**.

**isFull/isEmpty** now become obvious:

- isEmpty:   `return top == -1`
- isFull:    `return top == MAX_SIZE`

**PUSH**: adds one elements to the top of the stack:

```
    if (!isFull)
    {
       top++;
       A[top] = new_element;
    }
```

I'll let you figure out the rest; the idea is to update the **stack pointer top**  and always keep an eye on how much space you have available.